# How do I parse a signed request in Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to create a FB credits callback page, and need to parse the signed request coming in. I can write something manually, but it seems like this is something that should be in the SDK somewhere but I can't seem to find it in the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call the static method `Parse` on the `FacebookSignedRequest` class as shown below (with your app secret, and the signed request):

```cs
var DecodedSignedRequest = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(FacebookContext.Current.AppSecret, SignedRequest);
```

Now you will see all the data (in JSON format) from the signed request in `DecodedSignedRequest`.

Answer (score 24):

**Starting from v6:**

```cs
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic signedRequest = fb.ParseSignedRequest("app_secret", Request.Params["signed_request"]);
```

Comment: plus one on this.  I did the PM > Install-Package Facebook, and then tried the line of code in the one that was marked as answer for this stackoverflow question, and, it says "The name FacebookSignedRequest does not exist in the current context" with the red squiggly line in visual studio. your code does however work.

Comment: FacebookSignedRequest was part of v5 in Facebook.Web.dll. It was removed in v6

Comment: @prabir how could we obtain those all information or API reference of FB CSharpSDK? I cannot find anywhere in http://csharpsdk.org/ or github

Comment: checkout the samples https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk, csharpsdk.org does need some love. feel free to fork and send pull request https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk.github.com

Comment: @prabir sounds good :) I'd love to contribute to the awesome work!